# What order would these compounds elute in a 3:1 hexanes:ethyl acetate TLC run?

Tags: chromatography

I would figure the order would be (in order of smallest Rf to largest) W, Z, Y, X. Is the carboxylic acid more polar than the acetic anhydride?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making predictions about elution order is always guesswork but based on my experience I would expect acetic acid to streak off the baseline, The benzyl alcohol to be of low Rf but above the acetic acid, the benzyl acetate Y to run high and I really don't know about the acetic anhydride, I suspect it will hydrolyse on the plate to give you more acetic acid so you will not see a separate spot. How are you planning on visualising these?

Comment: I'm given a "plate" with 4 distinct spots and asked to propose an order of elution to the above compounds.

Comment: If the acetic anhydride does not hydrolyse then it will run ahead of X. In real life the acetic acid will not give a distinct spot more a smear but it will be the lowest - so my answer is Y,W,X,Z but it is a somewhat unreal example.